# LINQ Join with where condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I can use LINQ's Join with Lambda notations no problem, but I can't work out how one would then add a `where` condition.

```
var q = query.Join(context.CustomerIds,
    x => x.CustomerId,
    y => y.CustomerId,
    (x, y) => new CustomerLookupResult()
    {
        dob = x.DateOfBirth.ToString(),
        forenames = x.Forenames,
        surname = x.Surname,
        loyaltyNo = y.Identifier,
        customerId = x.CustomerId
    });
```

The table I'm joining the first to contains the `loyaltyNo` in its `Identifier` column, but also contains other information in the same column and so uses a second column `IdentifierTypeCode` to allow filtering.

So how do I now add `.Where(x => x.IdentifierTypeCode == "LOYALTY")` like I would in SQL. Appending this to end refers to the new object.

Comment: Without knowing the content of the two lists, something like: `var q = query.Join(context.CustomerIds.Where(x=>x.IdentifierTypeCode=="LOYALTY"),`

Comment: Of course, that's it! Thank you. Put it as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I think joining  in LINQ are easier understood when written with Query syntax  over the lamdas https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to the Join takes any IEnumerable, so you can apply the `Where` at that point, or earlier

```
var q = query.Join(context.CustomerIds.Where(x=>x.IdentifierTypeCode=="LOYALTY"),
    x => x.CustomerId,
    y => y.CustomerId,
    (x, y) => new CustomerLookupResult()
    {
        dob = x.DateOfBirth.ToString(),
        forenames = x.Forenames,
        surname = x.Surname,
        loyaltyNo = y.Identifier,
       customerId = x.CustomerId
    });
```

alternatively, if you don't like to put too much on one line:

```
var filteredLoyalties = context.CustomerIds.Where(x=>x.IdentifierTypeCode=="LOYALTY");
var q = query.Join(filteredLoyalties,
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could apply your `Where` before doing the join.

```
var q = customerLoyalties
        .Where(x => x.IdentifierTypeCode == "LOYALTY")
        .Join(customers,
              x => x.CustomerId,
              y => y.CustomerId,
              (x, y) => new CustomerLookupResult()
              {
                CustomerId = y.CustomerId,
                Name = y.Name,
                IdentifierTypeCode = x.IdentifierTypeCode
              });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this way to achieve that using Linq.

```
var match = from t1 in context.orders
                    join t2 in context.orderdetails on
                           new { t1.OrderID } equals
                           new { t2.OrderID }
                    join t3 in context.products on
                           new { t2.ProductID } equals
                           new { t3.ProductID }
                    where t3.ProductID == id
                    select t3;
        return match.ToList();
```